# I want to change the Text when ever I press the text button many times

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am not able to make the texts button work as it have to show different color text names when the button is pressed. I have mentioned the function call too but the result is same.
[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const DemoScreen(),

    );
  }
}

class DemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoScreen({Key? key}): super(key:key);
  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _DemoScreenState createState() => _DemoScreenState();
}

class _DemoScreenState extends State<DemoScreen> {
  final Random _randomColor=Random();
  Color _circleColor=Colors.white70;
  String displayText='Type here';
  var string=['Red','Green','Blue','Random','Restart','Texts'];
  void changeText(){
    setState(() {
      displayText=string[Random().nextInt(string.length)];
    });
  }
void restart(){
    _circleColor=Colors.white70;
}

  void _updateColor(Color color){
    setState(() {
      _circleColor=color;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Change Color'),


      ),
      body: ListView(
        children:[ Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children:[Center(
            child:Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: _circleColor,
              ),
            ),

          ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Red'),
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      _updateColor(Colors.red);
                    });
                    },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Green'),
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      _updateColor(Colors.green);
                    });
                    },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Blue'),
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      _updateColor(Colors.blue);
                    });
                    },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Random'),
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      _circleColor=Color.fromRGBO(_randomColor.nextInt(400),_randomColor.nextInt(200),_randomColor.nextInt(500), 10);
                    });
                    },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('restart'),
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      restart();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],),

            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  changeText();
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Texts'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have created all the buttons correctly but I want to know what is the wrong in text button that I cant make it workable.

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: Actually while adding code it showing error and i cant resolve the error. With error i cant upload it.

Comment: you can minimize the snippet and include more description,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: is `string` a variable?

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: how can i get a text Red whenever i Click the button red? and same goes to other buttons too. Can i make it workable in this code??

Comment: did you solved your problem?